# How does parent template pass data to child template?

Tags: meteor

So I have serverl base templates:

```
<template name="Base1">
  <div>basetitle1</div>
</template>

<template name="Base2">
  <div>basetitle2</div>
</template>
```

and the base templates is included in different templates.

```
<template name="Parent1">
  {{> Base1}}         # basetitle1 => Parent1.Title1
  {{> Base2}}         # basetitle2 => Parent1.Title2
</template>

<template name="Parent2">
  {{> Base1}}         # basetitle1 => Parent2.Title1
  {{> Base2}}         # basetitle2 => Parent2.Title2
</template>
```

`basetitle1` and `basetitle2` are different when in different parent templates.

So how can I pass data from parent template to child template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass data to the children template via [Object creation using keyword arguments](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#inclusion-and-block-arguments).

Try this:

```
<template name="Parent">
  {{> Base1 basetitle1=Title1}} # Get Title1 from a helper or data
  {{> Base2 basetitle2="Parent.Title2"}} # Pass a string
</template>

<template name="Base1">
  <div>{{basetitle1}}</div>
</template>

<template name="Base2">
  <div>{{basetitle2}}</div>
</template>
```